# Fatal Exception During Run-Time of Deserialization Class (Binary formatted-data)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception, deserialization, fatal-error

I am instantiating a deserializing class to fetch data from a binary-formatted data file.  This appraoch seems to work fine most of the time, except when some of the data files get larger than 2-4 MB, and the following exception is thrown (at the code line with comments, below):

"The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x722de24f, on thread 0x30e0. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."

Here is the code:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class deserializedata
    Public Property sernumrows As Integer
    Public Property sernumcols As Integer
    Public Property serx As Object(,)
    Public snumrows, snumcols As Integer
    Public sx As Object(,)
    Sub New(ByRef snumrows As Integer, ByRef snumcols As Integer, ByRef sx(,) As Object, ByVal sfilename as String)
        Dim param_obj(0) As Object
        param_obj(0) = sfilename
        Call deser(param_obj)
    End Sub
    Sub deser(ByVal param_obj)
        sfilename = param_obj(0)
        Using stream As FileStream = File.Open(sfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
          Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
          Dim myser As Object = formatter.Deserialize(stream) 'this is where exception is being thrown
          snumrows = myser.sernumrows
          snumcols = myser.sernumcols
          sx = myser.serx
          stream.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with the Late Binding.  I just deserialized 12MB (output = 18 MB) to a typed object 12 times in a loop with no error.  I use BF and PB-N a lot and never seen that error.

Comment: Would opening a different BF saved using a different format during serialization cause this error?